# Issue signing Ionic APK

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to sign my APK with this command:

```
'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\keytool.exe' -genkey -v -keystore packingapp.keystore -alias packingapp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

but am getting the error:

```
At line:1 char:54
+ 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\keytool.exe' -genkey -v -keys ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-genkey' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:62
+ ... :\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\keytool.exe' -genkey -v -keysto ...
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token '-v' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I can navigate to that directory and run keytool just to confirm it is there.... following the ionic documentation I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: Try going to the directory where keytool.exe is located and run the command, also open the command prompt as Administrator

Comment: Also the command you are using is used to create a key, not to sign the apk

Comment: Try using the command like this: keytool -genkey -v -keystore keyname.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Comment: it looks like the same thing if I try it in the actual directory also

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin> keytool -genkey -v -keystore packingapp.keystore -alias packingapp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ keytool -genkey -v -keystore packingapp.keystore -alias packingapp -k ...
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Did you try it in the same directory where keytool is located??

Comment: Did you see if keytool is in the directory??

Comment: yes I was able to navigate to that directory and run keytool. It then gives me a list of commands available so it is there. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin

Comment: so I just tried it in the directory where keytool exists from command_prompt and it seems to be working. I try the same thing from visual studio code and I get the error

Comment: Okay good! Did you open the command prompt as Administrator??

Comment: use this command to sign the apk: jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA  -keystore keyname.keystore apk_path alias_name

Comment: Also make sure to run this command where jarsigner is located, this should work without opening the cmd as Administrator